# Имя "Console" не существует в текущем контексте. Visual Studio 2017 c#

Tags: c#

Перешел на Windows 10. Поставил Visual Studio 2017 года. Создаю новый проект, пишу примитивный код для вывода "Hello". Пытаюсь набрать Console - выдает ошибку:

> Имя "Console" не существует в текущем контексте

Я упустил какие-то нововведения? Потому что раньше все прекрасно работало.

Сам код:

```
using System;

class Hello
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Это точно весь код? Все неймспейсы, которые есть в классе? Это точно консольное приложение?

Comment: это точно не скриптовый файл? Добавьте пространство имен и попробуйте скомпилировать с ним

Comment: Отключить консоль не могут 100%. Вы что-то не так сделали. Даже проверил у себя. Всё работает

Comment: Убедитесь, что Вы выбираете именно консольное приложение  https://i.stack.imgur.com/WF2sr.png

Comment: проверь мой проект должно работать https://yadi.sk/d/PcV9pkfg3Kr6wR

Comment: Ты reference какие-нибудь не удалял из проекта?

Comment: Думаю, что вы по ошибке создали не приложение под .NET Framework, а под какой-нибудь .NET Standard.

Answer (score 3):

Собственно, вот.[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какие должны быть добавлены ссылки на проект - можно увидеть на изображении. Скорее всего ты создал не консольный проект / удалены ссылки.